# The Discord Bot is not responding as expected

Tags: python

I have coded a discord bot with python and it should greet a member when he join the server , but it is not greeting .

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN','ODMyMTU..........')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!, Hello have a great time with us . By Anurag'
    )

client.run(TOKEN)
```

The code is working fine.

```
GodBot has connected to Discord!
```

Comment: The code looks fine though?

Comment: It will only run the first time the user joins the server. This will not greet the user everytime.

Comment: no it is not doing that.

Comment: Tell you what, post an invite to your server here and run the bot. I'll join and check if I get any message and I'll leave after.

Comment: Try doing simply `member.send("welcome")`. Also, you may need to enable the members intent in your bot settings if you haven't already.